# C# import of Adobe Illustrator (.AI) files render to Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, file-format, adobe-illustrator, rasterizing

Anyone knows how to load a .AI file (Adobe Illustrator) and then rasterize/render the vectors into a Bitmap so I could generate eg. a JPG or PNG from it?

I would like to produce thumbnails + render the big version with transparent background in PNG if possible.

Ofcause its "possible" if you know the specs of the .AI, but has anyone any knowledge or code to share for a start? or perhaps just a link to some components?

C# .NET please :o)

Code is most interesting as I know nothing about reading vector points and drawing splines.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very non-trivial task. You essentially have to implement a PostScript rendering engine!

Comment: I know, I am not trying to build a new Illustrator or PDF rendere, I just want a quick way to get an overview of files + use them on a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if Gregory is right that ai files are pdf-compatible, and you are okay with using GPL code, there is a project called [GhostscriptSharp](https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp) on github that is a .NET interface to the Ghostscript engine that can render PDF.

Comment: I better check this out before concluding anything. Thanks so far

Comment: looks promising! GhostscriptDevices: { ... pngalpha ... }

Answer (score 2):

With the newer AI versions, you should be able to convert from PDF to image. There are plenty of libraries that do this that are cheap, so I would choose buy over build on this one. If you need to convert the older AI files, all bets are off. I am not sure what format they were in.

Comment: interesting approach. .AI -> PDF -> Bitmap ... problem would be the output with transparency I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnGetAIThumb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Illustrator.Application app = new Illustrator.Application();
    Illustrator.Document doc = app.Open(@"F:/AI_Prog/2009Calendar.ai", Illustrator.AiDocumentColorSpace.aiDocumentRGBColor, null);
    doc.Export(@"F:/AI_Prog/2009Calendar.png",Illustrator.AiExportType.aiPNG24, null);  
    doc.Close(Illustrator.AiSaveOptions.aiDoNotSaveChanges); 
    doc = null; //
}
```

Illustrator.AiExportType.aiPNG24 can be set as JPEG，GIF，Flash，SVG and Photoshop format.

Comment: wouldnt that require Illustrator installed on the computer? this was thought as a service running on a webservice, so I dont think they will install an Illustrator client on it.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Tested that with [Pdf2Png](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pdf2Png/) and it worked fine with both .PDF and .ai files.
But I don't know how it will work with transparents.

```
string pdf_filename = @"C:\test.ai";
//string pdf_filename = @"C:\test.pdf";
string png_filename = "converted.png";
List<string> errors = cs_pdf_to_image.Pdf2Image.Convert(pdf_filename, png_filename);
```