# Can't use Image.FromStream for .ai file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, filestream, memorystream

I am trying to convert an .ai file to Image, but the line

```
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Utils.LoadImage("icon.ai")))
```

returns invalid operation exception.
The function Utils.LoadImage returns a byte[].
Here is the rest of the code:

```
ZipArchiveEntry hus_icon = zip.CreateEntry("icon.ai");
    using (Stream photoStream = hus_icon.Open())
    {
        var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Utils.LoadImage("icon.ai")));
        var imageBmp = new Bitmap(image);
        imageBmp.Save(photoStream, image.RawFormat);
     }
```

Comment: Read the discussion here around `.ai` files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784030/c-sharp-import-of-adobe-illustrator-ai-files-render-to-bitmap.  Basically, `.ai` files are PDFs and you have to use a `GhostScript` rendering engine to convert the files.

Comment: I was hoping there was simpler way, but thank you